# Android Studio: Layout

Tags: android, botón, layout

Tengo un pequeño problema que es que no puedo ajustar el Botón a la pantalla a pesar de ajustar los layouts, aún usando el imán. Vamos, que no hay forma.
Lo curioso es que el texto sí se acomoda cuando abro el emulador.
He estado viendo por youtube pero no hay modo.

Adjunto capturas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sugiero revises la información que se encuentra en el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dale al botón que te sale la 'X Roja', ubica todos los widgets a tu antojo, y por último dale al botón de la Varita, y te hará todos los Constraints o restricciones.

> ### Sin Restricciones:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> ### Con Restricciones:
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]